# Error about finding 'strings.h' in htmlcxx

Tags: c++, html

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ParserDom.h>
using namespace std;

using namespace htmlcxx;

int main()
{

ifstream bucky;
string str="";
    bucky.open("C:\\tasks\\TEST2.txt");

if(!bucky.is_open()){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
char word[50];  
bucky >> word;
str.append(word);
str.append(" ");    
while(bucky.good())
{

    bucky >> word;
    str.append(word);
    str.append(" ");
     }

//cout<< word<<" "<<endl;
bucky >> word;
str.append(word);
str.append(" ");

HTML::ParserDom parser;
tree<HTML::Node> dom = parser.parseTree(str);
//Print whole DOM tree
cout << dom << endl;
 }
```

---

Hi, I am using htmlcxx , I installed it, included its header files and libraries to my projects, and wrote my code as above
In brief, I opened a html file , put it in string, and then used html parser to write it. but I got the following error:

```
c:\...\htmlcxx-0.84\html\parsersax.tcc(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'strings.h': No such file or directory
```

I wonder if you could please help me to solve this problem.**

Comment: What is your build environment?

Comment: In Microsoft Visual studio c++. I added the header of #include <ParserSax.h>,but it still shows the error message. the problem is that it cannot find the strings.h!

Answer (score 2):

I think `strings.h` is a unix header file. Basically there are two different headers for the string library: `string.h` and `strings.h`. Those define slightly different prototypes. There should be a proper way to include the appropriate one using macros to test your compilation environment. Something like

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <string.h> 
#else
#include <strings.h>
#endif
```

I don't know which one is standard on Windows, this is just an example. If you are using third party code, it might not be portable. You should have a look at their headers and see if they are using code like the one above.

Edit:
try this quick and ugly fix: create a file `strings.h` which constains:

```
extern "C" {
#include <string.h>
}
```

That might work, depending on which functions they use...

**Edit:**

They do use this kind of macros in [ParserSax.tcc](http://code.google.com/p/wiibrowser/source/browse/trunk/source/html/ParserSax.tcc?r=13):

```
#if !defined(WIN32) || defined(__MINGW32__)
#include <strings.h>
#endif
```

So it might be a problem with your mingw installation. Try to find this file manually on your system.

Comment: Well, yes. I didn't provide a fix for it, just the cause ;) Now edited

Comment: But why is the error related to parsersax.tcc and it tell us that cannot open strings.h? I have already used string.h in my codes header. I tried to edit the code as you wrote but I still have the error.

Comment: You might have string.h on your system, not strings.h. If you create the later manually, insert the code I wrote and add its path to the compiler, the 'no such file or directory' error will definitely disappear. You might encounter further problems if some functions are undeclared, if it is the case you should update your question.